# Concurrency on DocumentDB

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

This is a newby question on DocumentDB. We want to use DocumentDB for our application. We have multiple users changing data that is stored in a DocumentDB. How can we asure that one user does not overwrite the changes of another user?

Answer (score -6, accepted):

DocumentDB does not protect against concurrency. If you post a new version of the document over an existing the old document will be overwritten. If you can to protect against concurrent writes you have to use the timestamp of the document. Every document in documentDB has a timestamp of the last action.

On every update you can check if the timestamp of the document you want to update is equal to the one that you retrieved or if it has changed. If is has changed the user does not have the most recent version and you can cancel the update.

The best thing is to create a stored procedure so you can put this logic inside a stored proc and make your application agnostic of it.

Comment: There's a built-in ETag mechanism that deals specifically with this. Checking timestamp won't prevent the server from rejecting writes based on ETag (two writers can check for timestamp simultaneously).

Comment: David's is really the better answer here. "Optimistic concurrency", "ETag", these are the correct terms. It's not apparent that the ETag is a timestamp. Also, I would not say sprocs are best for this simple situation of writes coming from two users. The ETag mechanism is simpler and easier to deal with error handling than sprocs. Sprocs _might_ be best if you are reading and writing in the same transaction or if you are doing multiple writes that need to be consistent with each other. I also favor sprocs for writes to do data validation.

Answer (score 21):

DocumentDB has *optimistic concurrency* and has an `ETag` on each document. If the ETag has changed when doing a write, the write fails (if the ETag changed, that means someone else modified the document). In this condition, you'd need to re-read and re-modify the document in question.

See the faq [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/documentdb-faq/) for more info.

Comment: Specifically you can use the request options and accessCondition property to provide the etag and IfMatch condition.

Comment: https://peter.intheazuresky.com/2016/04/28/documentdb-revisited-part-3-concurrency-in-documentdb/ has more detail on ETag usage.