# Can I read/load a document from Azure Cosmos DB and acquire a writing lock on it at the same time?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

Basically I want to know that only one party is going to change the document. I want to avoid situation when 2 different instances of a worker role or different worker roles will read the same state of the document and then each will write  its own modification, potentially different. Sequential writes may easily go fine one after another, but this is not what I want.

This writing lock should auto expire after some time if write will not happen for whatever reason.

I heard some rumors that this is possible, but I cannot find this in the documentation.

Comment: I think this question is a near-duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38123752/272109).

Comment: I think the requirement in this question is quite different than the question you linked. ETag based concurrency is essentially sequential one and that’s not the OP is after.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

AFAIK, what you're looking for (acquiring write lock) is not supported by Cosmos DB at least as of writing of this answer. What's supported today is [`Optimistic Concurrency using ETags`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/database-transactions-optimistic-concurrency#optimistic-concurrency-control) that is suitable for sequential writes but that's not you're looking for.

Just thinking out loud, you can however make use of [`Lease`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/lease-blob) functionality available in blob storage and use that in conjunction with your Cosmos DB write operation.

Essentially what will happen is your worker processes will try to acquire a lease on a blob for certain duration (15-60 seconds). Only one worker will be able to acquire a lease. That worker will have an opportunity to update the document in Cosmos DB for the duration it has acquired the lock. The other worker process will have to wait till the lease has been expired or the 1st worker has explicitly broken the lease.

This is somewhat similar to `Leader Election Pattern` described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/leader-election.

Comment: Thanks for your considerations. IMO Cosmos management should implement the same lease that you are pointing at in storage accounts. Well, the most reasonable would be to do the same with the doc in the Cosmos DB itself. Maybe this is too complex for Cosmos guys.

Comment: You can submit your feedback regarding this to Cosmos DB team here: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db.

Comment: @Web-Intern this isn't a complexity issue. Cosmos DB is designed to optimize for write throughput. You can't simultaneously provide a write latency SLA with a database that allows users to put locks on data.

Comment: @Mark, Hm. Do you see any word about complexity in my post above? I do not. I think the same that 10-ths milliseconds write SLA with lock guaranties in distributed database is impossible. The issue is that Cosmos docs do not state that.