# Ensuring atomicity of operations/transactions in SPs in Cosmos db

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I have questions on two different scenarios.

**Scenario 1:**
Currently we are following the pattern of pre and post conflict query checks, to maintain states of the documents. In short,
Our SPs have following pattern,

1. Pre Conflict check – check if document A is in state S1.
2. Create a document B which has transitive relationship (B depends on A).
3. Post Conflict check - check if document A is still in state S1, if not fail.

**Questions**
 1. Could the document A be changed after Post Conflict check but before the transaction is committed?
If yes, what is the best approach for Mitigating this?

**Scenario 2:**
We want to lock our documents to prevent any edits or allow partial edits.

**Questions**

1. Does cosmos db have any feature to implement locks?
2. Can we leverage triggers for lock? (explained below)

Triggers as locks
We could implement lock by creating a separate LOCK document (since all types of documents can have only unique ids, we will have one lock per document).
If we want to change/replace a particular document we could have a pre trigger that executes and checks the lock.

What are the pros/cons of using triggers for locking (also from performance perspective)?
Can the above *scenario 1* be replaced by using pre and post triggers?

More definitively is *post triggered fired after a Replace document call has committed or before it*?

Answer (score 1):

Answers to both of your questions can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/database-transactions-optimistic-concurrency.

**Scenario 1:**

Thought I have not tried it but for you 1st scenario, I believe you can use `Stored Procedures` in Cosmos DB. Assuming both of your documents are in the same partition, you will pass both document A and B to a stored procedure. There you would create document B. Once it is created, then you will check the status of A. If A is not in the desired state (S1), you would throw an exception and that will rollback the entire transaction.

**Scenario 2:**

As such locks are not available in Cosmos DB but what you are trying to do can be accomplished by using `Optimistic Concurrency` in Cosmos DB. This is accomplished by making use of `_etag` property on the documents. Optimistic concurrency prevents a writer to accidentally overwrite changes done by another writer in a multi-writer scenario.

Comment: What happens when my check for S1 is successful and then the document A changes to S2 state just before entire transaction is committed?

Comment: We evaluated eTags but don’t believe it to be the right solution. 
We have scenarios where we have long running operations. Once our long running operations start we do not want any/partial change to a set of documents. In such a case even if we read eTag while starting the long running operations, we cannot block other service requests from operating on these set of documents. 
Which is why we require a lock construct.

Comment: `What happens when my check for S1 is successful and then the document A changes to S2 state just before entire transaction is committed?` - You can throw an error at that time from the stored procedure and that should rollback the transaction. Regarding your 2nd comment, unfortunately locking is not available in Cosmos DB at the moment. You can possibly make use of `Lease Blob` functionality somehow in your code. Please see this for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60147614/can-i-read-load-a-document-from-azure-cosmos-db-and-acquire-a-writing-lock-on-it/60148403#60148403.

Comment: Our team does not want another dependency (Azure blob). I think that’s where trigger would be useful. Let me try out!!